# Listar objetos dos meus Buckets - Amazon S3 SDK PHP

Tags: php, lista, amazon-aws, sdk

Meu projeto é:

- Listar meus buckets
- Listar os objetos de cada bucket

Criei um foreach pra listar os buckets e funcionou perfeitamente.

Não aconteceu a mesma coisa com o foreach dos objetos.

```
$buckets = $s3->getIterator('ListBuckets', []);
foreach($buckets as $bucket) {

    $objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', [ 'Bucket' => $bucket ]);
    foreach($objects as $object) {
        // não retornou nada e ainda deu erro
    }

}
```

Erro na página exibe:

`Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the ListObjects operation: [Bucket] must be a string or an object that implements __toString(). Found array(2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\backup\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Api\Validator.php:65 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\backup\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Middleware.php(79): Aws\Api\Validator->validate('ListObjects', Object(Aws\Api\StructureShape), Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\backup\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\S3\S3Client.php(405): Aws\Middleware::Aws\{closure}(Object(Aws\Command), NULL) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\backup\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\S3\S3Client.php(428): Aws\S3\S3Client::Aws\S3\{closure}(Object(Aws\Command), NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\backup\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\S3\S3Client.php(362): Aws\S3\S3Client::Aws\S3\{closure}(Object(Aws\Command), NULL) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\backup\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\S3\S3Client.php(381): Aws\S3\S3Client::Aws\S3\{closure}(Object(Aws\Command), NULL) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\backup\vendor\aws\aws-s in C:\xampp\htdocs\backup\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Api\Validator.php on line 65`

Alguém saberia como fazer essa listagem de objetos dentro dos buckets funcionar?

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. O idioma oficial usado aqui é o Português, você poderia traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é que o método `ListBuckets` retorna um array multi-dimensional com os dados dos buckets.

Tente substituir a seguinte linha:

```
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', [ 'Bucket' => $bucket ]);
```

por esta

```
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', [ 'Bucket' => $bucket['name'] ]);
```

Caso ainda não tenha funcionado, mostre a saída do comando `var_dump($bucket)`.

Comment: Eu tentei com $bucket['Name'] e também não deu certo.

Uma coisa que fiz agora foi criar outro usuário pra testar um novo acesso e consegui listar os objetos tranquilamente....

Parece que tem algo a ver com algum tipo de restrição nas credenciais do outro usuário...

Comment: Você poderia dizer qual erro apresentou agora?
Se possível, cole também a saída do comando var_dump($buket)

Comment: var_dump($bucket): `array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(12) "SATLCARRETAO" ["CreationDate"]=> object(Aws\Api\DateTimeResult)#110 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-10-17 11:48:32.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(2) ["timezone"]=> string(1) "Z" } }` 

erro: `Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\PermanentRedirectException: Encountered a permanent redirect while requesting https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/SATLCARRETAO?encoding-type=url. Are you sure you are using the correct region for this bucket?`

Achei o erro, ascredenciais estão sem permissão suficiente e as regiões são 3, e não 1 como defini

Comment: Usei como referencia o único bucket que SEI que tenho acesso e consegui listar os objects sem problemas, terei que verificar essa situação das credenciais, tirei um problema do projeto :-D obrigado pela ajuda!